# How to combine tee, sed and grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed

I have a command after which I place `| tee >(sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g' >> ~user/filepath/file.txt)` The `tee` is redirected to `sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g'` which removes the unwanted color formatting. After that the `sed` is appending `>>` the clean result into `file.txt`. So far so good...

Now I want to exclude certain lines from being appended into the text file.
I found [this article](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-can-i-cat-or-grep-a-file-to-ignore-lines-starting-with-654683/) that suggested using `grep -v '^#'` to match inverted `-v` lines starting with # `'^#'` and inverted matches on empty lines using `grep -v '^$'`

My question is... how/where in my `| tee >(sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g' >> ~user/filepath/file.txt)` can I include the `| grep -v '^#' | grep -v '^$'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code `sed … >> ~user/filepath/file.txt` is responsible for setting up `sed` that appends to the file. You seem to know this.

Now if you want the output of `sed` to be filtered by `grep` and later by another `grep`, and only then appended to the file, then you need a pipeline like this:

```
sed … | grep … | grep … >> ~user/filepath/file.txt
```

Fill in the ellipses according to what you have found.

In your case the whole above code should be inside the `>()` syntax you're using. The ultimate command will be like:

```
… | tee >(sed … | grep … | grep … >> ~user/filepath/file.txt)
```

`grep`s will affect what gets written to the file; they won't affect what gets printed to the stdout of `tee` (i.e. to the terminal probably).

---

`sed` alone can be used to delete lines containing the patterns. In your case the `sed` command will be:

```
sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g; /^#/d; /^$/d;'
```

Use it inside `>()` instead of your original `sed` command. Now you don't need to add `grep`s to this `sed` because `sed` does their job.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `| tee` is not important here. All of your filtering happens inside of `>(...)`, which contains a whole *separate* command line that just happens to be confined within a subshell, but otherwise has syntax elements independent of the outer command, so you can focus on that part alone and ignore the "outer" pipeline entirely.

(That is to say, it's *not* just an ordinary `>` redirection – the `>(...)` is a single unit; an inline syntax element that branches off another pipeline in parallel, as opposed to redirecting the current one.)

So the command you're working with is just:

```
sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g' >> ~user/filepath/file.txt
```

It's usually more useful to filter text *after* removing the formatting codes, so you would insert the 'grep' filter after 'sed', but before the redirection:

```
sed $'etc' | grep -v '^#' | grep -v '^$' >> ~user/filepath/file.txt
```

(The two filters could be combined into a single `grep -E -v '^#|^$'`.)

Within the original command line, it would look like this:

```
... | tee >(sed | grep | grep >> ~user/filepath/file.txt)
```